# gem update --system - "Mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

so I'm currently having a problem after I switched from rvm to rbenv. I'm a command line newb, and relatively new to rails and ruby as well. Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this here?

```
$ gem update --system
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 22 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in `initialize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Also, running gem pristine --all doesn't work, nor does rails new.

Comment: Can you list what steps you did through to swap from rvm and rbenv? Did you make sure that rvm is completely uninstalled? It looks to me like it's looking for the gems in the wrong place...

Comment: i was trying to have another version of ruby running (2.1.2 instead of 2.2.1), but it wouldn't seem to work. So I did rvm implode and installed rbenv as it says to do on github.

Comment: That's the correct way to install rbenv. Can you do a rbenv global in the terminal to see what version of Ruby you have set? (If you don't, set it.) Also, do an echo $PATH to make sure that rbenv is added to your PATH.

Comment: So for my version of ruby, I've got 2.1.2 set now, which is what I wanted. And my path is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Andrew/.rvm/bin, which is odd because I thought that with implode .rvm should have been erased? So obviously I did something wrong... but when I try the rvm command it's not found.

Comment: I can no at least use the rails new command, but anything to do with gem does nothing still. Edit: nevermind it is no longer working again either... with no change from me.

Comment: Did you follow the directions about rbenv init and adding rbenv to your path in your bash_profile? You should do that, because current your gems are still pointing to rvm.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to do that, but even after that fix I get the problem /Users/Andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 22 (Psych::SyntaxError), and my path is now /Users/Andrew/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Andrew/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Andrew/.rvm/bin. which seems just totally out of whack.

Comment: It looks weird, but it is correct. It looks like your error is now coming from the Psych gem. Have you tried gem uninstalling that and then running gem update?

Comment: It's not letting me type any commands for gem at all, so I can't even uninstall it through that. should I go along that path and manually uninstall? Even sudo isn't working to uninstall here.